# Split string with regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I have been trying to split a string using regular expression in android without any success.

The string is formatted like this **id;value|**
For example :

```
String valueString = "20;somevalue|4;anothervalue|10;athirdvalue|5;enoughwithvaluesalready";
```

I use this method to try o split the string.

```
public void splitString(String valueString){
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([\\d]+);([^\\|]+)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(valueString);  
    boolean matches = m.matches();
}
```

When I run it in the [Rubular-regex-editor](http://rubular.com/r/dGDvQrIV7d) it looks fine, in Android no matches are found. Any ideas?

Comment: to me, the error seems to be in escaping backshalshes. else regex `([\d]+);([^\\|]+)` seems fine.

Comment: Why don't you use `String.split` instead of your own solution?

Comment: @KARASZIIstván I was just about to post that. Split on | followed by split on ;

Comment: @BunjiquoBianco I did the same, then I decided to ask it first :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried your example, It will work only add .* at end of your Regx

```
    Log.i("MainActivity ", "Matches " + valueString.matches("([\\d]+);([^\\|]+).*"));
```

Above line return true

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)

Describe in above function

Answer (score 2):

the method `matches()` tries to match the regex against the the complete string. And this does clearly not match.

`find()` will find the next matching substring.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use [`String.split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) instead of writing your own solution?

Like:

```
final String[] entries = valueString.split("\\|");
for (String entry : entries) {
  final String[] fields = entry.split(";", 2);
}
```

Comment: I tried that but for some reason it split every character in the String. When I escaped it with \\| it worked fine :)

Comment: without the escaping it's looking for nothing or nothing (as split takes a regex argument), which weirdly matches everything.